# How many child processes are created in the following code

Tags: c, process, operating-system, fork, child-process

```
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 

int value = 5; 
int main() 
{
    pid t pid; 
    pid = fork(); 
    if (pid == 0) {
    value += 15;
    return 0;} 
    else if (pid > 0) { /* parent process */ 
       wait(NULL);
     printf("PARENT: value = %d",value); /* LINE A */
                 return 0;}}
```

How many child processes are created and what value is printed in Line A?

Comment: What stops you from simply trying it out?

Comment: Please note that Pico style is not really an accepted (acceptable) layout for C code.  Please choose one of [Allman or 1TSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) unless there are compelling reasons to do otherwise — and you should be ready to explain why those reasons are compelling.  With the sloppy indentation shown, you aren't even following Pico style very closely.

Comment: Parent process will print 5. Only one process is created.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try it?

Just single child is created and the parent prints value 5 as it's not modified in the parent process. The global variables have a copy in each of the processes, they are not shared.

Comment: Yes, actually i just started learning C , I am just little confuse about child process and parent process.

Comment: "Single child is created and it prints 5" wrong: child doesn't print anything. Fork return val for child is 0. "As it's not modified in the parent process" wrong: parent/child process can modify value as they wish, it won't affect the other process as 'value' is a global variable which are duplicated at fork. Every process has its own value.

Comment: @TonyTannous : Correct comment, Tony, I admit it could have been confusing from my original sentence. I amended that sentence.